# in ProcessExplorer what is the difference between remote address = 127.0.0.1:0 and *:*?

Tags: networking, ports, sysinternals

In Process Explorer when I select a process click on "TCP/IP" tab it shows 5 columns: Protocol, Local Address, Remote Address, State, Service. Under Remote Address, I often see entries such as 127.0.0.1:0 and *:*. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is loopback address, e.g the address that loops back to the same computer. If a process has Remote Address 127.0.0.1, it will listen only in loopback address so the service should be accessible only from the same computer.

If the process has  Remote Address *.*, it will listen on all available ipv4 address assigned to this computer so the service should be accessible from the another computer connected with this computer.